# NHibernate QueryOver parent object

Tags: linq, nhibernate, queryover

I have a model with two classes :

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Product> { get; set; }  
}

public class Product
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public decimal Amount { get; set; }

}
```

which is represented in two different tables in database.

How do I use QueryOver<> to query Products based on their **Category and their Amount** and finally select Products.

In entity framework I would write something like :

```
context.Categories.Where(s=>s.Id == @1)
                  .Select(s=>s.Products)
                  .Where(s=>s.Amount>12333).ToList();
```

OR

```
context.Products.Where(s=>s.**Category**.Id == @1 && s.Amount > 12333).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should *(almost must)* extend the relation from Product to Category:

```
public class Product
{
   ...
   public Category Category { get; set; }
```

It is already in DB, so there is no reason why to hide it from the POCO entities.

Then, as stated in documentation:

- [16.4. Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-associations)

We can do it like this:

```
var results = session
   // here we get query related to Product
   .QueryOver<Product>()
     // here we filter Product
     .And(p => p.Amount > 12333)
   // here we join the Category
   .JoinQueryOver(p => p.Category)
     // and do some farther filtering
     .Where(c => c.Id == 1)
   // list of products
   .List<Product>()
```